# How to resolve Sprockets::DoubleLinkError application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sprockets

I'm experiencing this error while pushing to heroku repo

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::DoubleLinkError: Multiple files with the same output path cannot be linked ("style.css")
remote:        In "/tmp/build_f430cee0cae4a9543fac20926137c7cc/app/assets/config/manifest.js" these files were linked:
remote:          - /tmp/build_f430cee0cae4a9543fac20926137c7cc/app/assets/stylesheets/style.css
remote:          - /tmp/build_f430cee0cae4a9543fac20926137c7cc/app/assets/stylesheets/style.scss
```

I have tried these suggestions:

1. I deleted the .css file and kept the .scss (there are no duplicates AFAIK)
2. cleared temp directory with `heroku run rake tmp:clear`
3. reset repo with `heroku repo:reset -a <app name>`
4. `heroku repo:purge_cache -a <app name>`

But I still keep getting the error when I push to the Heroku remote

Comment: Did you check in your changes into the repo too after deleting the .scss file?

Comment: Try to clean the precompiled assets on Heroku with `rake assets:clobber`

Answer (score 7):

For me, this simply occurred because I had **two style sheets where I should have had only one**. In my case, I had

```
myapp/app/assets/stylesheets.application.css
```

AND

```
myapp/app/assets/stylesheets.application.css.scss
```

where I should have had just one of those

I removed `application.css` and the problem went away