# Sprockets::DoubleLinkError - Multiple files with the same output path cannot be linked ("application.js")

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, heroku, installation, sprockets

Rails version: 7.0.3.1

Ruby version: 3.1.0p0

React version: 18.2.0

I'm trying to add React to my existing rails app and followed the tutorial here - https://medium.com/rd-shipit/how-to-set-up-a-rails-7-project-with-react-and-jest-f2e016bfbdf3
Since I already had an existing rails app, I installed esbuild using the instructions here - https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails

```
Run ./bin/bundle add jsbundling-rails
Run ./bin/rails javascript:install:[esbuild|rollup|webpack]
```

However, when I try to run the app locally, it fails with

```
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
remote:
remote:          app/assets/builds/application.js      1014.9kb
remote:          app/assets/builds/application.js.map     1.6mb
remote:
remote:        Done in 0.17s.
remote:        W, [2022-08-30T02:32:56.872963 #271]  WARN -- : Removed sourceMappingURL comment for missing asset 'assets/application.js.map' from /tmp/build_54e3859f/app/assets/builds/application.js
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::DoubleLinkError: Multiple files with the same output path cannot be linked ("application.js")
remote:        In "/tmp/build_54e3859f/app/assets/config/manifest.js" these files were linked:
remote:          - /tmp/build_54e3859f/app/javascript/application.js
remote:          - /tmp/build_54e3859f/app/assets/builds/application.js
```

I'm very new to the whole frontend work and have never worked before on frontend. I'm just learning all this firehose of information so I'm quite stuck here as I've tried multiple things without any success. And quite honestly, I don't understand a bunch of this stuff. The things I've tried are:

- Renamed `app/javascript/application.js` to `app/javascript/application2.js`. This works on local but fails when I push to heroku.
- Deleted `application.js` and `application.js.map` in `app/assets/builds/*` and only kept the `app/assets/builds/.keep` file.
- Tried running the commands here - [How to resolve Sprockets::DoubleLinkError application.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613142/how-to-resolve-sprocketsdoublelinkerror-application-css)

app/javascript/application.js:

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
// import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
// import "controllers"
import "./react/src/index.js"
```

I tried uncommenting `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"` and `import "controllers"` but that just gives different errors.

I'm out of ideas to try at this point. What am I missing here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only thing I see is that you are using Javascript from 2 places: `app/javascript/applications.js` and `app/assets/javascript/application.js`

The good way is as you did from `app/javascript/application.js` (don't comment out @hotwired and Stimulus Controllers, it is not where the problem is comming from)

Basically with the new way to handle Javascript with JSBundling, the application.js file in `app/javascript/` will be bundled into `builds` folder. Then grabbed by Sprockets to be fingerprinted and compressed.

Sprockets will also compress and fingerprint everything from the `app/assets/javascript` folder and then you end up having two files named the same.

If you have no `app/assets/javascript` folder then there may be a problem with your `app/assets/config/manifest.js` file. You probably try to pass to sprockets both the `app/assets/builds` folder AND the `app/javascript` folder. Then you end up adding to your app, both the bundled and unbundled file.

Comment: Thank you! It was definitely an issue with my `app/assets/config/manifest.js` file like you said. It was also checking the `app/assets/builds/` directory there, leading to the conflict.

Comment: Great. Though it is the builds folder that holds the bundled files and should be referenced in manifest. Everything in `app/javascript` is rather source files than need be dealt by the bundler.

Comment: Just to make this obvious for other new people like me, I removed //= link_tree ../builds from app/asses/config/manifest.js and this fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious, what's the implication for removing the `app/assets/builds` links? Is it related to dev or prod environments?

Comment: I think you should rather delete the `//= link_tree ../../javascript .js` part, as you want to have the `application.js` from the build folder rather. I did this, and everything is perfect